# Classic ASP Page Calling batch Script

Tags: iis, vbscript, asp-classic

I have two classic asp pages in which I had to call a batch script. The first one is working:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>    
<%'Roda o arquivo BAT para chamada do script powershell
Set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
wshell.Run "\\w102xnk172\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\DCT_NEW\App\copy_items.bat" 
Set wshell = Nothing

'Cria o arquivo .txt de bloqueio, que o script powershell excluirá em sua finalização.
Dim fs,tfile
Set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set tfile = fs.CreateTextFile("\\w102xnk172\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\DCT_NEW\DB\running_script.txt")
tfile.Close
Set tfile = Nothing
Set fs = Nothing

'Quando não existir mais o arquivo, a interface continua.
filename = "running_script.txt"
path_db = "\\w102xnk172\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\DCT_NEW\DB\"
path_file = "\\w102xnk172\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\DCT_NEW\DB\running_script.txt"

Set fs = Server.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

While fs.FileExists(path_file) = True
Wend
%>
```

This code runs my script and creates a "running_script.txt", then checks if it still exits, so no code runs until it ends. My script, at it's end, delete that file. This is working fine, and the other on is just as simple:

```
<%@LANGUAGE="VBSCRIPT" CODEPAGE="65001"%>
<%
    page = REQUEST.QUERYSTRING("page")

    If page = "ofs" Then
        Set wshell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
        wshell.Run "C:/www/gppintranet/scripts/ofs.bat"
        Set wshell = Nothing
    End If

    response.Redirect("/gppintranet/view/home.asp")
%>
```

But for some reason it does not call my script. I'm automatically redirected to the home page. I've debugged, it is getting into my `If` statement and the script is running properly.

I'm running this application in IIS 10.0.15063.0, if it is of use.
What is wrong? I see no difference between them.

**EDIT**: I have run the non-working script at the working enviroment, and it didn't work there as well. I've checked and both IIS are at the same version and with the same settings. The working script is:

```
@echo off
start "" http://w102xkj172/DCT_MASTER/update_dct_p2p.asp
timeout /T 5

echo Waiting for P2P DCT's information update...
:verify_locked
if exist \\w102xkj172\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\PC_REPORTS\exemplo\DCT_MASTER\p2p_running.txt (
    goto :verify_locked
) else (
    echo Copying files...
    robocopy /IS \\w102xkj172\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\PC_REPORTS\exemplo\DCT\DB\ \\w102xnk172\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\PC_REPORTS\exemplo\DCT_LINE_P\DB\ DCT.mdb
    robocopy /IS \\w102xkj172\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\PC_REPORTS\exemplo\DCT\DB\ \\w102xnk172\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\PC_REPORTS\exemplo\DCT_LINE\DB\ DCT.mdb
    robocopy /IS \\w102xkj172\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\PC_REPORTS\exemplo\DCT\DB\ \\w102xnk172\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\PC_REPORTS\exemplo\DCT_LINE_1\DB\ DCT.mdb
    robocopy /IS \\w102xkj172\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\PC_REPORTS\exemplo\DCT\DB\ \\w102xnk172\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\PC_REPORTS\exemplo\DCT_LINE_3\DB\ DCT.mdb
    robocopy /IS \\w102xkj172\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\PC_REPORTS\exemplo\DCT\DB\ \\w102xnk172\c$\inetpub\wwwroot\PC_REPORTS\exemplo\DCT_LINE_4\DB\ DCT.mdb
)
exit
```

And the non working is:

```
@echo off
START "" http://example.aspx
```

Comment: It's not a good idea do to that, if it works at all.  You have to give too many permissions to your IUSR user to to that.  To see if it's possible, run your application under `administrator` account.  What actions are done by the batch file?  Thoses actions cannot be done from IIS?  Remember IIS run in a limited profile.  Some actions, that interact with desktop/user by example, cannot be done under that profile.

Comment: I know that this is not a good idea, but it's not my aplication and it was built that way. The script file that is working runs copy of items, the one that is not working opens a url in the default browser (IE). Both the IIS servers are the same version and have the same settings. I've tried running the non-working script at the working enviroment, and it didn't work, also. The problem is in the script. I'll update the question with it's content.

Comment: `the one that is not working opens a url in the default browser (IE)`.  This interact with user.  The only way this can works is if the admin session is open on the server and IIS run from that session.